# What is "Geometry of Banach spaces" precisely?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

I've been seeing this around lately in books that study classical Banach spaces. I can't find an exact description of this subject anywhere so I figured somebody on SE would know how to describe it; the word "Geometry" in the title is what confuses me.

Comment: As with geometry in general, most of the times people don't mean the same thing. As far as I can tell though, usually "Geometry" of Banach Spaces reffers to trying to understand certain "weaker" properties Banach spaces have compared to Hilbert spaces. Example of such a property would be the so called type and co-type trying to imitate the parallelogram law.